# MemberwiseClone and Guids

Tags: c#

If I do the following:

```
var item2 = item1.MemberwiseClone();
item2.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Whatever new `Guid` `item2` gets, it will change it for `item1` as well. Isn't this incorrect since a `Guid` is a value type? This happens for both `Guid` and `Guid?`.

Comment: Is `ID` just an auto property?  It could potentially do all sorts of weird things if it's not.  Also, this code shouldn't care of `Guid` is a reference or value type.  If it was a reference type you'd still be changing the reference to be a new object (although you're right, it is a value type).

Comment: That code can't work as MemberwiseClone is protected.  Also I have tested it using a code similar to Candide below and it clearly does not happen as you have said.

Comment: @Tonnie can you provide us with sample _working_ code that reproduces your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be something wrong with your implementation. Here's an example that demonstrates usage:

```
class Program
{
    class A 
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        public A Clone()
        {
            return (A)this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var item1 = new A();
        item1.ID = Guid.NewGuid();

        var item2 = item1.Clone();
        item2.ID = Guid.NewGuid();

        Console.WriteLine(item1.ID);
        Console.WriteLine(item2.ID);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If you run the code as a console app, you will see that the Guids differ as the documentation says.

Comment: Well, I figured it out, I have a Property with type of a class I have, and its ID was the same. After I clone I just call new and clone THAT as well, and all is good.